# PHPExcel error opening the excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter()
```

must be an instance of PHPExcel, null given, called in `C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\print.php` on line 19 and defined in `C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php` on line 129

[PHPExcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hii2F.png)

Comment: $_POST['submit'] must not be set.

Comment: Can you post the code of "print.php" file please.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and then edit you question accordingly. Just pasting your error message wont going to help you get the problem solved.

Comment: my codes are on the picture attached but ill copy it here

Comment: <?php 
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
require_once ('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

echo "connected";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$objPHPExcel = new PHPexcel();

$objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0)
   ->setCellValue('A1','Test')
      ->setCellValue('A2','Testing');

}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "testing.xlsx"');  
header('Cache-Control : max-age=0'); 


  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('output.xlsx');


?>

Comment: <?php 
require_once('PHPExcel.php');
require_once ('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

echo "connected";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$objPHPExcel = new PHPexcel();

$objPHPExcel -> setActiveSheetIndex(0)
   ->setCellValue('A1','Test')
      ->setCellValue('A2','Testing');

}
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= "testing.xlsx"');  
header('Cache-Control : max-age=0'); 


  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('output.xlsx');


?>

Answer (score 0):

Try to Install PHPExcel Library via Composer <kbd>composer require phpoffice/phpexcel</kbd>. and then include autoload.php file.